# Is there no "multiple match vector" function in R?

Tags: r, match

I was trying to find a "readily available" function to do the following:

```
> my_array = c(5,9,11,10,6,5,9,13)
> my_array
[1]  5  9 11 10  6  5  9 13
> my_test <- c(5, 6)
> new_match_function(my_test, my_array)
[1] 1 5 6
# or instead, maybe:
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 6
# [[2]]
# [1] 5
```

For my purposes, `%in%` is close enough, since it will return:

```
> my_array %in% my_test
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

and I could just do:

```
> seq(length(my_array))[my_array %in% my_test]
[1] 1 5 6
```

But it just seems that something like `match` should provide this capability: a means to return multiple elements from the match.

---

If I were to create a package simply to provide this solution, it would not be strongly adopted (for good reason... this tiny use case is not worth installing a package).

Is there a solution already available? If not, where is a good place for me to add this? As I showed, it's easy enough to solve without a new function, but for `match` to not allow for multiple matches seems crazy. I'd ideally like to either:

1. Find out that I'm wrong and there is a direct function to accomplish this, or
2. Be able to alter `match` itself so that it can return multiple occurrences.

But my impression (right or wrong) has been that any adjustments to the `base` code are more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: You mean `which(my_array %in% my_test)` ?

Comment: Or `lapply(my_test, function(x) which (my_array==x))`

Comment: Well, with data.table `data.table(a = my_array)[.(my_test), on=.(a), which=TRUE] # 1 6 5` or `data.table(a = my_array)[.(my_test), on=.(a), .I, by=.EACHI]` for a table.

Comment: Yes, @Sotos and @yfyang those are certainly good alternatives, and more graceful than what I'd proposed.  But it still doesn't solve the point I was trying to make: this is something that `match` itself should be able to solve.  Otherwise, why bother using `match`?  Multiple match cases **must** be more useful than just stopping on the first one you find, right??

Comment: In my answer, "==" is an operator and the `%in%` is a wrapper for the `match` function. For `match` it is designed to work on the vectors matching (not on the long vector such as list).  The return value is the same length as the first parameter. So if we want to return a list, the easiest choice is `lapply`.  There are other ways too. For example `match(my_array,my_test)` will return some kind of the result you want. If length(unique(my_test))<<length(my_array), then some work on `match(my_array,my_test)` should be much faster than my lapply version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple cases, `which(my_array %in% my_test)` or `lapply(my_test, function(x) which(my_array==x))` works fine, but those are not the most efficient.

For the first case (just knowing which are matches, not seeing to which elements they correspond), using the `fastmatch`-package may help, it has the `%fin%` (fast-in) function, that keeps a hash table of your array so that subsequent lookups are more efficient.

For the second case, there is `findMatches` in the `S4Vectors`-bioconductor-package. (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/S4Vectors.html)

Note that this function doesn't return a list, but a `hits`-object. To get a list, you need the buioconductor `IRanges`-package as well (and use `as.list`). (https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/IRanges.html)